# How invoke this code in Curl?

Tags: php, json, curl

I need to turn this code in curl for HTTP REQUEST

```
POST https://www.mylink.com/dir/comment/itemID

HEADER
Content-Type: application/json
Token-Key: {tokenKey}

BODY
{
 "quantity":"{quantity}"
}
```

I tried this way:

```
curl -v --url https://www.mylink.com/dir/comment/itemID -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Token-Key:tokenKey" --data "quantity=myquantity"
```

But it shows me error code 405.

I'd like some help.

Comment: I think you could try this using postman app

Comment: Is there PHP to this? It sounds like you are trying to run the CURL from command line.

Comment: yes, I try to run in command line, but I would like to get in PHP if it's possible.

Comment: I added but it's still the same error

Comment: the --data flag automatically adds the -X POST. You don't need to add it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your data encoding is not JSON, change it like this:

```
--data "{\"quantity\": myquantity }"
```

But this is not why you are getting a 405 method not allowed. It's possible you are making a request to an endpoint that does not allow POST.

Comment: Finally it works, I needed to include a user and password credentials at the end -u user:pass

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using https://requestb.in in order to debug your request.
This one just works as you wanted to work:

`curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Token-Key:tokenKey" -d "{\"quantity\": 10101}" https://requestb.in/11zr87w1`

However it `HTTP 405` states that `post` is not allowed.

---

*Note: I have no relation with requestb.in, I am just a developer who uses it*

Comment: ... when you use `-d`, you should however not use `-X POST`. It is superfluous at best.

Comment: @DanielStenberg you might be right, I just pasted example from the site.

Comment: @DanielStenberg let me know if they change it :)

Comment: Them responding or not doesn't change my point though... https://twitter.com/bagder/status/924268003969175552